# Is 夜だから some kind of idiomatic expression?

Tags: manga, slang, idioms

[image: manga]

In the following dialogue from a manga:

> A: 漫画かよ…！
>
> B: わははどうしたみつや、寝ぼけてた？
>
> A: …別に、なんで泣いてんのって思って
>
> B: うーん、あー、夜だから？
>
> A: 何ソレ

The character wakes up and tells his friend who was crying over reading a manga "I was wondering why you were crying"

And his answer is "夜だから"because it's night". Is this some kind of slang or idiomatic expression?

Comment: Better wait for some native's input here, but to me, it seems that A was expecting some kind of more profound or important reason as to why B was crying, and B just comes up with a mundane, silly explanation 夜だから？ "because it's night?", which prompts A to say 何ソレ meaning "LOL, what?" because A is not reading the air at all or he is trying to hide his true feelings behind this paltry excuse.

Comment: Is this from a published manga? If so, what is the title and the author?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no. It has nothing to do with an idiom or culture-specific phrase.

(Neither of the two guys seems to think that 夜だから is a valid reason in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

The idea that night makes you sad is kind of a cliche in songs and poems. If you search for 泣きたい夜 and 歌, you will find a lot of songs with lyrics using the expression (or a similar one), including 『泣きたい夜に』 by Nakajima Miyuki.

With that in mind, it might be the case that the answer is supposed to be baffling because the character sounds suddenly poetic (in a cliche-y way).

I'm not aware of a set phrase like that that would be in a dictionary, or a specific, very famous song that could be referenced, though. I think it's just that many songs employ the idea.